# Show GPS availability and Accuracy in Iphone SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, gps

How to program to show the GPS availability and Accuracy level in an iphone? and it has to wipe the previous lat, lon info in label.

Answer (score 0):

There is a class in iOS sdk called CLLocationManager. Go though its documentation in the XCode or look for some sample example.
http://mobileorchard.com/hello-there-a-corelocation-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

[CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager) has a method [`locationServicesEnabled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423648-locationservicesenabled) to check if the service is enabled or not

```
[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]
```

Comment: Could u explain Briefly please.

Comment: [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] returns YES if service is enabled else it returns NO