# Show GPS availabilty(Yes or NO) and Accuracy(in meters) in iphone

Tags: iphone, sdk, gps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show GPS availabilty and Accuracy in Iphone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897204/show-gps-availabilty-and-accuracy-in-iphone-sdk)

Hi All.,
          I want to show in a UILabel that GPS availability is there or not and i want to display the accuracy of GPS in meters. Please anyone guide me.